# How can I efficiently get a list of matching Amazon S3 files?

Tags: php, optimization, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, file-exists

Assume 200,000 images in a flat Amazon S3 bucket.

The bucket looks something like this:

```
000000-1.jpg
000000-2.jpg
000000-3.jpg
000000-4.jpg
000001-1.jpg
000001-2.jpg
000002-1.jpg
...
ZZZZZZ-9.jpg
ZZZZZZ-10.jpg
```

(a 6 digit hash followed by a count, followed by the extension)

If I need all files matching `000001-*.jpg`, what's the most efficient way to get that?

In PHP I'd use `rglob($path,'{000001-*.jpg}',GLOB_BRACE)` to get an array of matches, but I don't think that works remotely.

I can get a list of all files in the bucket, then find matches in the array, but that seems like an expensive request.

What do you recommend?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Amazon provides a way to do this directly using the S3 api.

You can use the `prefix` option when calling listing S3 objects to only return objects that begin with the prefix. eg using the AWS SDK for PHP:

```
// Instantiate the class
$s3 = new AmazonS3();

$response = $s3->list_objects('my-bucket', array(
    'prefix' => '000001-'
));

// Success?
var_dump($response->isOK());
var_dump(count($response->body->Contents))
```

You might also find the `delimiter` option useful - you could use that to get a list of all the unique 6 digit hashes.